# How do I cast an enum to an Integer to handle overflow/wraparound?

Tags: ada

I'm learning ada and I'm trying to implement an addition overload for an enum.

Basically I want to be able to add an Integer to a Day type and get the resulting Day value. So MONDAY + 2 => WEDNESDAY.

Here is my simplified code:

```
procedure overload is                                                                                                             
    type Day is (                                                                                                                 
        Sunday,                                                                                                                   
        Monday,                                                                                                                   
        Tuesday,                                                                                                                  
        Wednesday,                                                                                                                
        Thursday,                                                                                                                 
        Friday,                                                                                                                   
        Saturday                                                                                                                  
    );
    day1 : Day := Monday;
    function "+" (left: Day; right: Integer) return Day is                                                                        
        -- how would I handle this here? I want to basically say
        -- if Day + Integer > Saturday then
        --   wraparound back to Sunday
        return DayValue;
    begin
       for x in 0 .. 7 loop
          Ada.text_io.put_line("Monday + " & Integer'Image(x) & " = " & Day'Image(day1 + x));
       end loop;
end overload;
```

Comment: I think it is better in your case to make `Day` a modular type and use constants for names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the 'Pos and 'Val attributes to do it.  'Pos returns the position of the supplied day relative to the first option (0 indexed) while 'Val takes a Pos value and returns the day type value:

```ada
return Day'Val(Day'Pos(Left) + Right);
```

For wraparound check the 'Pos value of Saturday vs the 'Pos value of left + the right value and use Day'Val(0) for Sunday

Or switch your input type of Right from Integer to Natural and use modulus math:

```ada
return Day'Val((Day'Pos(left) + Right) mod 7);
```

You can even get fancy and make a constant for the 7:

```ada
Day_Mod : constant := Day'Pos(Day'Last) - Day'Pos(Day'First) + 1;
```

and then it becomes

```ada
return Day'Val((Day'Pos(left) + Right) mod Day_Mod);
```

Comment: It may also be useful to modulo `right` by `7`. If we add 41 days do Sunday, we end up in the exact same day as adding 6 days.

Comment: @Chris That's also something that can be added.  However, I think at that point I would maybe define a separate type for the Right parameter, like type Day_Offset is new Natural range 0 .. 6, but it sounded like maybe the OP wanted to keep go past 6 (at least their test loop goes past it).

Comment: Ah ok, 'Pos is what I was looking for, thank you! One more question, since Pos returns the index of the enum, I'm assuming it won't return the actual value. Is there way to get that Integer value for if I did something like " for Days use ( Monday => 20, etc...)

Comment: @KaibutsuX if you are using GNAT you can use Enum_Rep to get the 20 and Enum_Val to convert the 20 back to Monday.  The upcoming Ada version, Ada202x will add these as language defines rather than just GNAT specific extensions.  You can also create an array indexed by Day:  Day_Convert : array(Day'Range) of Integer := (10,20,...) and then you just call Day_Convert(Monday) to get the integer number

Comment: Also `Unchecked_Conversion` should get you the actual representation value.

Comment: @Álex Definitely, though it's often tricky to use Unchecked_Conversion correctly.  For example, the OP should set a specific size for the Day type and ensure that they do the conversion to an integer type with the same size type.  It's often not a good idea to use Integer as is and instead use a sized integer type like Interfaces.Integer_32 or similar which can then be cast to Integer (and allows Ada to do the range check on the value).

Comment: In Ada there are no casts and no enums. There are type conversions and enumeration types, which may be what you're talking about. It's usually a good idea to use Ada terminology, as there's no guarantee people who could give a good answer will understand non-standard terms.

Comment: The portable way to convert between an enumeration value and its representation is with `Ada.Unchecked_Conversion`. It is important that the enumeration type and integer type have the same size, as Jere pointed out.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if I use unchecked_conversion on an enumeration type, that I actually wrap that in a function that calls the unchecked_conversion instance and then validates the data is within the constraints of the type before returning it.  The more recent extended return functionality makes doing this a lot nicer:  return Result : My_Type := Unchecked_Conversion_To_My_Type(Source) do if not Result'Valid then raise Constraint_Error; end if;  end return;  I don't know if that is strictly necessary, but it makes me feel better!

Answer (score 3):

While you have an answer to get the position value associated with a enumeration value, do not think this is the same as an enum in C. Ada enumerations are not numeric types.

You can iterate through a range of enumeration values using a for loop as in

```
for the_day in Day loop in loop
   Put_Line(Day'Image(the_day));
end loop;
```

If you want to print the current day and the next day you can use the 'Succ attribute.

```
for the_day in Day loop
   Put(Day'Image(the_day) & " the next day is ");
   if the_day = Day'Last then
      Put_Line(Day'Image(Day'First));
   else
      Put_Line(Day'Image(the_day'Succ));
   end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but not what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`PragmARC.Wrapping`](https://github.com/jrcarter/PragmARC/blob/Ada-12/pragmarc-wrapping.ads):

```
with PragmARC.Wrapping;

function "+" (Left : Day; Right : Integer) return Day is
   package Wrapping is new PragmARC.Wrapping (Item => Day);
   use Wrapping;

   Result : Day := Left;
begin -- "+"
   Change : for I in 1 .. abs Right loop
      Result := (if Right < 0 then Wrap_Pred (Result) else Wrap_Succ (Result) );
   end loop Change;

   return Result;
end "+";
```